# How to check what other software connecting to internet

Tags: internet

I am using version "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS", I found that OS internet connection much more slow at these days, even can not view Youtube smoothly. So would I know that is there any command or any tool I can use, to view any other software connecting the internet at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this helps, could you please copy and paste this command to your terminal:

```
lsof -i
```